# Terminating H-1 Visa in Korea - What Steps Do I need to Take?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, south-korea, identity-cards

I currently have the H-1 Working Holiday visa, and intend to leave Korea soon. I can find surprisingly little information on the web on what steps I need to take.

Can I just get up and leave? Do I have to book an appointment somewhere to return my alien card? Any guidance would be appreciated

Edit: Per the [Singapore Embassy](https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/sg-en/brd/m_2444/view.do?seq=721174&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=) website and [Chung-Ang University](https://neweng.cau.ac.kr/cms/FR_CON/index.do?MENU_ID=460) website:

> "ARC [alien registration card] must be returned to the Immigration Office / immigration officer at the departure airport or port upon final departure."

It seems like I can return the card at the Immigration officer of the airport I depart from. There is also the hotline number `1345` from within Korea where I can ask more questions, so if there's no further answer by tomorrow, I will write one with what I find.

Answer (score 1):

You terminate your visa by handing over your Alien Registration Card to the Immigration officer on your way out. You need it until that moment. Inform the officer that you are leaving (early). If you are leaving on the last day of your visa, they will not hand it back, and if it's just a few days before expiry they'll ask whether you are coming back.

But if you are leaving early, inform them, and hand over the card – it's illegal to keep it (been there done that, have the scars).